# How do extensions install in openGL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I cannot find some information for this issue. Particularly, I want to install  GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility extension. How can I do it ( in Linux)?

Comment: extensions are intrinsic to the opengl driver that is installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have some misconception about what extensions are.

**Extensions are not plugins.** In other words, extensions are not something you can install alongside an existing OpenGL implementation to gain new functionality.

Extensions *are* functionality that a OpenGL implementation exposes in addition to the standard OpenGL functions of the OpenGL version the implementation supports. For example a OpenGL implementation may support all of OpenGL-2.1 but also parts of OpenGL-3.0 (but not everything from OpenGL-3.0). So the driver can not claim that it supports OpenGL-3.0, but it may advertise the supported subset as extension.

If you need a certain extension you must install a OpenGL implementation (= GPU + matching driver) that supports that extension.

Answer (score 1):

As *ratchet freak* said, it depends if it's already implemented in driver (and if your hardware support it)

You could rebuild the drivers (part of the [Mesa project](http://www.mesa3d.org/)) yourself from the latest source to get the latest extensions available, or depending on you distrib, you could fetch experimental or testing package using [pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning) (for debian based distrib)

Answer (score 1):

You could also obtain hardware implementing the opengl extension you need.

[Here](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/) is a database of opengl extensions with detailed hardware implementations.

For example [here](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/feature/GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility) is the report of which hardware support the GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility extension.